# Jenkins - Node focused testing

Tags: jenkins, hudson, jenkins-plugins

Just started working with Jenkins lately, I've been able to make it work with my needs but it isn't quite perfect.

A bit on what I'm doing with Jenkins and what I'm trying to accomplish.

What I have:
    - A test lab with multiple kinds of systems (400+ systems), and all different operating systems (Multiple versions of Windows and Linux) 
    - A standalone test suite of python scripts to test various functions on each system (100+ tests).

What I'm doing:
    - I currently have several Jenkins jobs set up to kickoff my standalone testsuite on a single test node. 
    - I then have another set of Jenkins jobs, that all they do is collect all the systems to run a job on and then kick off the proper job from the first set on all of the required nodes.

This works for me to kick things off, but not so much when when it comes to results.

When it comes to results, since all 400+ builds are ran from 2 jobs, the jobs show failed if any one test on any of the test nodes fails.

I need to see how things trend on a node by node basis. I know I could create a job for each node, but that would be 400+ jobs, which is not scalable or maintainable if I need to add more nodes or make a slight change to job.

If my descriptions are not clear, please let me know so I can clarify. What I really would like to know is there an existing way plugin to do what I need, could I possibly develop a plugin to do this or is there a completely different tool that I should be looking at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ideas you could try which might fit your needs

- [Matrix Jobs](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Matrix+Project+Plugin)
- [Multijob](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multijob+Plugin)
- [Job DSL](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Job+DSL+Plugin)

### Matrix

Matrix jobs allow for the same job to be run for different parameters. One of these parameters is a node/label which limits which node that axis runs on (only available when you have more than one node).

### Multi

Multijob uses standard jobs and runs them in a containing job. You can phase jobs and have conditional behaviour

### Job DSL

Builds and rebuild your jobs programatically, including matrix jobs and multijobs

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm currently using the Matrix Configuration for my Jobs that kick of my test suite, as the test suite has multiple sections. However, I have toyed with it, and don't believe it can do quite what I want. It looks like the Multijob and Job DSL might have some promise though, I will have to investigate them.

Comment: Thanks again for the help. Job DSL makes maintaining large quantities of Jobs rather easy.

Comment: You're welcome. Job DSL is my favourite Jenkins plugin